# Using loop to save multiple plots to PDF

Tags: r

I've done a lot of searching and realize that this is asked often, but the previous posts have not been able to solve my problem.

I have a loop that makes plots, and I am trying to save each plot to one pdf. The code is below (note: "singles" is a data frame with 62 rows)

```
# name of saved pdf file
pdf("plots.pdf")

# make a loop that makes a df for each row of data
for (i in 1:nrow(singles)){

       single_subj_df <- singles[i, 1:168]   

       single_subj_df_long <- melt(single_subj_df) # reshape to long

       single_subj_df_long$id <- i

       p <- ggplot(single_subj_df_long, aes(variable, value, group=factor(id))) +
              geom_line(aes(color=factor(id))) + labs(title = "Single Test Subject", 
                                                      x = "Misinformation (dotted lines)", 
                                                      y = "Slider")

       p + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
                 panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey96")) +
              geom_vline(xintercept = c(88,120,133), linetype = "dotdash")
}
dev.off()
```

The loop runs and I get the following output

```
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

If I just run the code inside the for loop by hand (replacing "i" with "1", "2", etc) the plots generate fine, so I don't think that part of the code is the issue. And after the loop runs, "i" is set to 62 so I know it's iterating through each time.

However, when I go to look at the PDF, it's only 4KB and I get an error when trying to open the file. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
butler

Comment: The `pdf()` needs to be at the beginning of the function and `dev.off()` at the end, so for each iteration a new plot will be created and closed. Also, look into `ggsave()` which is almost certainly better for `ggplot` than `pdf()`

Comment: If you are using this method, just before closing the loop, could you add `plot(p)`? I believe this is the reason it is not printing to the pdf.

Comment: It would just be `p` as it's a ggplot device. Good spot @jav

Comment: Awesome, got it to work! Thank you both.   Also, @Phil, I will look into ggsave()!